# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED zoom hosting

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, web-hosting

I am trying to up my website in zoom hosting. Whenever I run my app, all my css and js is not working when I checked my inspect element it shows these errors "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED"

Question: How can I fix this error? Is the .htaccess also the same with the localhost that I am using?

Comment: What Browser are you using?

Comment: The browser that I am using is chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome as browser Check Network Tab to see what file failed to get downloaded.

IN Chrome to get to the network tab from the menu select More tools/Developer tool and then Network tab.

Usually, you will see a resource name, such as a picture or icon or image.

If you use IE9+ you can click on F12, or click Developer Tools on the Debug menu and look at Network Tab.

Comment: I only got IE8 version. When I pressed F12, there's no network tab

Comment: Oh. there's no network tab. I need to upgrade first my IE8

Comment: Didn't you say you also use Chrome? I updated my answer to explain how to get to Network Tab on Chrome.

Comment: I mean, I also tried in my IE but my version is just 8